# Figuring out the force using Newton's 2nd Law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Here's a problem on my test review:

> A 12 kg crate resta on a horizontal surface and a boy pulls on it with
>   a force that is 30° below the horizontal.  If the coefficient of
>   static friction is 0.40, the minimum magnitude force he needs to start
>   the crate moving is:

Okay, so I found the equation for the forces in the Y direction:
$$\sum F_{Y} = F_{N} - mg - F\sin\theta = 0$$
$$F_{N} = mg + F\sin\theta$$

And the X direction:
$$\sum F_{X} = F\cos(\theta) - F_{f} = 0$$
$$F\cos\theta = F_{f}$$

Solving for the force:
$$F\cos\theta = u_{s}F_N$$
$$F\cos\theta = u_s (mg + F\sin\theta)$$
$$F\cos{-30°} = 0.40 \left[(12 kg)(9.8 \frac{m}{s^2}) + F\sin{-30°} \right]$$
$$F \left[\cos{-30°} - (.4)(\sin{-30°} \right] = 47.04 N$$
$$ F=44N $$

However, it looks like the correct answer was `71`.  Any ideas where I went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for $F_Y$ should be
$$\displaystyle\sum F_Y=F_N-mg+F \sin\theta\;.$$
All terms in such expressions should start out positive. They can turn negative later depending on the angle at which they're applied. In fact, if you wanted to be super-explicit you could write
$$\displaystyle\sum F_Y=F_N\sin(90°)+mg\sin(-90°)+F \sin\theta\;.$$
It's hardly necessary in this case, though.

Comment: If I do that, then I get 128.5 as my answer.  That is, unless I'm making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Working from $F\cos(-30°)=\mu_sF_N=0.4\left[9.807\times 12-F\sin(-30°)\right]$ gives $F=70.7$. Check your math.

Comment: Whoops!  I was just missing an addition sign somewhere.  Thanks!

Comment: ""I was just missing an addition sign somewhere."" The **force** was not with You!